# Save X509 certificate to a file

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I am working on a HTTPS client and I managed to establish a secure connection and get the X509 certificate using: 
`X509 *cert = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);` (ssl is SSL*).

How do I save the certificate to a file?
Also, I need to get "Subject DN" and "Issuer DN" fields from the certificate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-- *How do I save the certificate to a file?*

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
int PEM_write_X509(FILE *fp, X509 *x);
```

-- *Also, I need to get "Subject DN" and "Issuer DN" fields from the certificate.*

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
X509_NAME *     X509_get_issuer_name(X509 *a);
X509_NAME *     X509_get_subject_name(X509 *a);
```

Comment: `X509_NAME_oneline()` is useful to convert the `X509_NAME` structures to plain text strings.

Answer (score 3):

To encode the certificate into a file you can use this OpenSSL function:

```
int i2d_X509_fp(X509 *x, FILE *fp);
```

It encodes the X509 structure pointed by `x` into file using the DER encoding. More details on the [OpenSSL API reference](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html).

Comment: The correct form is `int i2d_X509_fp(FILE *fp, X509 *x);`